# Couldn't install dependancy using carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods, carthage

I've been installing dependencies using pods, but now i've tried carthage first time.
I've opened an issue on git also, but looking for a quick help.

Here's the github link of issue:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1765

Short Desc about Issue:

The following build commands failed:

CompileSwift normal x86_64
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

(2 failures)

My Xcode version is 8.0,
git version 2.8.4 (Apple Git-73),
and carthage version 0.18.1: Redundant Redundancy

Any help would be highly appricaited

Comment: How does your Cartfile look?

Comment: My cart file only contains this                                                                    github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had 3 versions of xcode installed 7, 8.0 and 8.1, I was trying on xcode 8 but I ended up using xcode 8.1 and changing the command line tool of xcode from preferences to xcode 8.1

hope this helps anyone else :)